# Scrapy Running multiple spiders from one file

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, scrapy

I have made 1 file with 2 spiders/classes.  the 2nd spider with use some data from the first one.  but it doesn't seem to work. here is what i do to initiate and start the spiders

```
process=CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(Zoopy1)
process.crawl(Zoopy2)
process.start()
```

what do you suggest

Comment: Welcome! Please, consider this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. It's not enough context to tell anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will run 2 spiders simultaneously.
Running spiders [sequentially](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.5/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process)  (start `Zoopy2` after completion of `Zoopy1`) can be achieved with `@defer.inlineCallbacks`:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
...

configure_logging()
runner = CrawlerRunner()

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(Zoopy1)
    yield runner.crawl(Zoopy2)
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run()
```

Alternative option (if it is suitable for Your task) - is to merge logic from 2 spiders into single spider Class,