# scrapyd deployed in KubeSphere，and when running scrapy selenium got exception:'twisted.internet.error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError'

Tags: selenium, scrapy, twisted, reactor, scrapyd

I deploy `scrapyd` in KubeSphere, I got expectation when I run `scrapy` and `selenium`:

```
2022-03-16T12:57:15+0000 [Launcher,1832/stderr]     return Crawler(spidercls, self.settings, init_reactor=True)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 82, in __init__
            default.install()
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 256, in install
2022-03-16T12:57:15+0000 [Launcher,1832/stderr]     installReactor(p)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/internet/main.py", line 32, in installReactor
2022-03-16T12:57:15+0000 [Launcher,1832/stderr]     raise error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError("reactor already installed")
        twisted.internet.error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError: reactor already installed
```

I don't have twisted installed separately. Why does it report that it already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Without code and package version, it is hard to guess what happens. If your program was once working, check your scrapy version. There is an [issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/5435) in latest 2.6 version. You could pin your scrapy at 2.5.1 .

If you are under developing scrapy scripts, you might want to run multiple spiders in a script. It is easy to mess up the pipeline and get `twisted.internet.error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError` error. You could check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67821739/scrapy-running-multiple-spiders-from-one-file).